# Issues with learning try/catch

Tags: java, intellij-idea, try-catch

I'm currently in a java course and trying to learn how to catch exceptions. In this case I have an input file that is only allowed to contain certains signs and must contain a goal and a start. I check all this in a seperate class constructor and want to insted of just telling the user something is wrong use a try/catch to tell the user that he did something wrong.

```
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        temp = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
           testString(temp);
        }
        catch (/*Don't know what to catch*/){
            System.out.println("Input file contains unvalid input");
        }
        mazeData.add(row, temp);
        row++;
    }
    try{
        containStartAndGoal();
    }
    catch(/*Dont know what to catch?*/){
        System.out.println("Input file have either no goal or start!");
    }
```

Currently this is my issue, i have tried to use a IOExecption but that does not seem to work. If I use just Execption i need to catch it every time i try to call this method. Which I do in both my test program and main program. I have tried to read as much as I can around here but don't seem to understand what I am suppose to do. Can I not try something if I don't throw it somewhere else? And what type of execption am I suppose to use when there is an input file that is incorrect. We didn't really get any information around how these work in school only that they exist.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `containStartAndGoal()`? Also, what do you mean by " but that does not seem to work"?

Comment: Why don't you first write the code without the try catch block and see what exceptions are thrown. You can then catch those exceptions.

Comment: It simply checks if a list contains a 'G' and a 'S'. Well i cant catch a IOExecption, the idea doesnt tell me why it only suggest to delete the catch operation. If i however use catch(Execption e) it works but then i have to throw a IOExecption everywhere where i call the constructor for the class

Comment: @MukeshKeshu Sounds much smarter but i have no idea how to see what exceptions that are thrown, how do i do that?

Comment: if "testString" and "containStartAndGoal" are simple methods which do not throw any exceptions, then there is no need of exception handling.

Comment: Just compile it. The compller will tell you what needs to be caught.

Comment: It pretty much depends on how you run the code. If you run through a command prompt, it gets shows in the command prompt.If you use an ide it will be shown on the console. Know that there will be exceptions only if calling methods itself return any exceptions.

Comment: @MukeshKeshu They only return a boolean value, they both simply contain a check that my list of strings never contains anything unallowed. However i have already handed this in and if they contained anything "illegal" i simply printed and exited the program. when the exercise was returned the teacher told me that it should throw a exception so the user can do something about it insted of the program exiting

Comment: @MukeshKeshu What are you talking about. It depends on what the compller requires you to catch, not on how you run it. You can't run it until it compiles, and you can't compile it until all checked exceptions are caught or declared to be thrown,

Comment: @user207421, From what i understand he is not catching a checked exception. He has put his try catch block for the methods, he wrote himself. These methods just does some simple printing.

Comment: @forsb - Did you get a chance to check the answer?